# Can I do a turn-based game with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Can I do a turn-based game with firebase-js or firebase-android? In my game idea, there will be rooms like poker.

Is it possible to make it only using firebase? Or do I have to use a server?

Comment: This is incredibly broad. Many games can be built using Firebase features without using a server. Whether that applies to your game depends on many factors. I propose you get started on building the game and report here with a more concrete question when you get stuck.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for reply dear Frank.